# Synthesizing Music in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio

Is it possible to synthesize (not just play *.wav / *.mp3) files in JavaScript? I.e. to write javascript code that (1) produces some PCM waveform and (2) pipes it to the speaker?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would imagine you can. In fact, one submission to the JS1k contest was a [JavaScript speech synthesizer](http://www.p01.org/releases/JS1K_Speech_Synthesizer/JS1K_Speech_Synthesizer.htm). I think this pretty much proves that music is possible as well (though I'll not define *music* here). A breakdown of the project can be found here: http://www.p01.org/releases/JS1K_Speech_Synthesizer/.

You might also find riffwave.js to be of interest: http://codebase.es/riffwave/. It has some pretty impressive examples on the demo page.

Jasmid is a MIDI file synthesiser which has been shown to create some horrendous retro MIDI files that take us all back to the days of Geocities and `bgsound`. You can view it on Github at https://github.com/gasman/jasmid, and hear a couple demos at 
http://jsspeccy.zxdemo.org/jasmid/.

Comment: JS1K speech synthesizer does not work for me. Do I need some plugin?

Comment: The riffwave demo, however, is pretty cool.

Comment: @user1311390 No, no plugins. You need a modern browser though that supports the `<audio>` tag.

Comment: lol, I had the volume really high when pressed the speech synthesizer (it scared my cat ¬¬) :D

Comment: +1 for geocities and bgsound ;)

Comment: MIDI often gets a bad rap from programmers but is still used regularly in the music industry for programming electronic instruments. The horrendous quality attributed to MIDI music is because of a bad soundbank (set of recorded instrument sounds), not MIDI itself. Play that same MIDI on a Korg keyboard or with a Garritan sound library and your mind will be blown.